# Pick the lengthier and give the index of the shorter in an R vector

Tags: r, function, vector

`setdiff()` requires its first vector argument to be lengthier than its second vector argument. To overcome this limitation, I'm trying to always put the lengthier of two arguments first and the shorter second.

`which.max()` gives the index (`ind`) of lengthier argument, but I wonder how to get the `ind` for the shorter argument without using `which.min()`?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
a = c("bob", "jim", "jon")
b = c("bob", "jim", "jon", "al")

NAMES <- list(a, b)

ind <- which.max(sapply(NAMES, length)) # index for lengthier of `a` and `b` 

setdiff(NAMES[[ind]], NAMES[[???]])#But what to put for ind of shorter arg: NAMES[[!ind]] fails
```

Comment: What if the lengths are the same? i.e. `NAMES = list(a = c('a', 'b', 'c'), b = c('b', 'c', 'd'))`

Comment: the `which.max` returns the index of the first max element.  So, in the example I showed, it would be `NAMES[['a']]`

Comment: My question is what do you want to get as output in that case.  If you need 'a' as the output, it gives that with the current code

Comment: "setdiff() requires its first vector argument to be lengthier than its second vector argument": this is false. Why do you think so?

Comment: @Reza In that case, create a condition `l1 <- lengths(NAMES); ind <- if(length(unique(i1))==1) 0 else which.max(l1)`

Comment: @Reza Regarding your question, both works, only thing is that if 'a' have elements that are not in 'b', then it would be returned without regarding the length.  `NAMES <- list(c('a', 'b'), c('c', 'f', 'h')); setdiff(NAMES[[1]], NAMES[[2]])`

Comment: @Reza Yes, that is when both vectors have the same elements.  I was talking about the case where the lengths are same but elements are different

Comment: @Reza Both works. The set difference is not commutative and of course you get different results. You might not have much clear what a set difference is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[` instead of `[[` (for a general case)

```
ind <- which.max(lengths(NAMES)) # lengths would be more efficient
```

Using the example where the `length` of `list` is only 2, use the `-`

```
setdiff(NAMES[[ind]], NAMES[[-ind]])
#[1] "al"
```

If the length of `list` is greater than 2, loop through the `NAMES[-ind]` with `sapply`

```
lapply(NAMES[-ind], setdiff, x = NAMES[[ind]])
```